# Catch 22: need apt-utils to install apt-utils?

Tags: installation, debian, apt-get

I was trying to install something else when I ran into this problem. So I tried to install apt-utils to solve it. But I couldn't install apt-utils, because well, my console tells me I don't have apt-utils:

```
root@napajohn:~# apt-get install apt-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-utils
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/129 kB of archives.
After this operation, 365 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  apt-utils
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Setting up dash (0.5.5.1-7.4em1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 75.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz by dash', none removed.
This should never be reached
dpkg: error processing dash (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bash:
 bash depends on dash (>= 0.5.5.1-2.2); however:
  Package dash is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing bash (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
configured to not write apport reports
                                      configured to not write apport reports
                                                                            Errors were encountered while processing:
 dash
 bash
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@napajohn:~#
```

I've tried this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/358943/what-does-debconf-delaying-package-configuration-since-apt-utils-is-not-insta

I've tried this but for me it doesn't include apt-utils:
[apt error: Could not perform immediate configuration on](https://superuser.com/questions/199582/apt-error-could-not-perform-immediate-configuration-on)

After doing a good amount of web searching, I am still lost for ideas. Help appreciated!

Running:

```
root@napajohn:~# cat /etc/debian_version
6.0.3
root@napajohn:~# uname -a
Linux napajohn 2.6.34 #4 Mon Oct 31 16:41:13 EDT 2011 armv7l GNU/Linux
root@napajohn:~#
```

Comment: Try `dpkg-reconfigure -a` or installing the wanted package with `dpkg -i` by downloading the `.deb` from the web interface to the Debian package archives.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Daniel. I didn't see it right away. However, I've managed to get everything working. I can't submit an answer yet because of low reputation though. I will in 6 hours when it lets me.

Comment: @JohnE this question would be appropriate for Super User or Unix and Linux. Either or. Since you figured it out and posted it here, we'll leave it here for now.

Answer (score 7):

I have resolved this issue, thanks to this thread post:
http://lists.debian.org/debian-embedded/2011/11/msg00037.html

The process I used:

```
root@napajohn:~# cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/dash.preinst
#!/bin/bash
set -e

divert() {
        dfile=$1
        ltarget=$2
        div=$(dpkg-divert --list $dfile)
        distrib=${3:-$dfile.distrib}
        temp=$dfile.tmp
        if [ -z "$div" ]; then
                # This differs from dpkg-divert's --rename because we
                # first make a copy of $dfile (the file being diverted)
                # in $distrib. Then, a symlink to $ltarget is forcibly created
                # from $dfile; this is performed in two stages with an
                # intermediate temporary file as ln -sf is not atomic.
                # dpkg-divert's --rename direct equivalent would be:
                # mv $dfile $distrib -- but we could end up without a symlink
                if [ -e $dfile ]; then
                        cp -dp $dfile $distrib
                fi
                ln -sf $ltarget $temp
                mv -f $temp $dfile
                dpkg-divert --package dash --divert $distrib --add $dfile
        fi
}

# Divert the following files if no diversion exists already
# It is currently used to prevent the files collision between bash and
# dash: they both provide the files in the package.
divert /bin/sh dash
divert /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz dash.1.gz \
        /usr/share/man/man1/sh.distrib.1.gz
root@napajohn:~# /var/lib/dpkg/info/dash.preinst install
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz.tmp': No such file or directory
root@napajohn:~# mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1
root@napajohn:~# /var/lib/dpkg/info/dash.preinst install
Adding 'diversion of /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz to /usr/share/man/man1/sh.distrib.1.gz by dash'
root@napajohn:~# /var/lib/dpkg/info/dash.preinst install
root@napajohn:~# dpkg --configure -a
Setting up dash (0.5.5.1-7.4em1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 75.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Setting up bash (4.1-3em1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/share/man/man7/bash-builtins.7.gz doesn't exist.
root@napajohn:~# apt-get install dialog
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dialog
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/183 kB of archives.
After this operation, 516 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  dialog
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
tar: ./control: time stamp 2010-11-27 17:03:26 is 344105762.627135945 s in the future
tar: ./md5sums: time stamp 2010-11-27 17:03:26 is 344105762.625823689 s in the future
tar: .: time stamp 2010-11-27 17:03:26 is 344105762.625457478 s in the future
Selecting previously deselected package dialog.
(Reading database ... 9114 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking dialog (from .../dialog_1.1-20100428-1em1_armel.deb) ...
Setting up dialog (1.1-20100428-1em1) ...
root@napajohn:~# dpkg --configure -a
root@napajohn:~# apt-get install apt-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-utils
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/129 kB of archives.
After this operation, 365 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  apt-utils
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
tar: ./control: time stamp 2011-06-28 19:49:06 is 362518839.816741658 s in the future
tar: ./shlibs: time stamp 2011-04-15 21:43:32 is 356132105.815368367 s in the future
tar: ./postinst: time stamp 2011-04-15 21:43:32 is 356132105.814819051 s in the future
tar: ./md5sums: time stamp 2011-06-28 19:49:06 is 362518839.814361287 s in the future
tar: ./postrm: time stamp 2011-04-15 21:43:33 is 356132106.813903523 s in the future
tar: .: time stamp 2011-06-28 19:49:06 is 362518839.813598348 s in the future
Selecting previously deselected package apt-utils.
(Reading database ... 9123 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking apt-utils (from .../apt-utils_0.8.10.3+squeeze1em1_armel.deb) ...
Setting up apt-utils (0.8.10.3+squeeze1em1) ...
root@napajohn:~# echo Hoorah!
Hoorah!
```

Comment: +1 for `echo Hoorah!`, even if ! normally yells at you.